# Compatibility issue between H2 DB queries and Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, h2

I'm developing an application which uses the H2 DB . But the queries which are in the H2 supported grammar are not supported by Sql server and vice versa . Is there any way to make the application work with a common query structure which supports both H2 and Sql Server ? 
Here are my queries ..
1st Query

SQL Server Syntax -

```
SELECT columns INTO  table_1 FROM table_2  WHERE conditions
```

H2 DB equivalent

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 AS  SELECT columns FROM table_2 WHERE conditions
```

*The above H2 query wasnt supported by SQL Server

2nd Query

SQL Server Syntax

```
UPDATE a SET columns FROM table_1 a JOIN table_2 b on keys WHERE conditions  INSERT INTO table_1(columns) SELECT columns FROM  table_2 WHERE conditions
```

H2 DB equivalent

1st part

```
 UPDATE table_1 a  SET column=(SELECT column FROM table_2 b WHERE conditions)
```

2nd part

```
 INSERT INTO table_1(columns) SELECT columns FROM  table_2 WHERE conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rewrite the queries.

The proper way to do that would be to create the target table and then say:

**INSERT INTO table2

SELECT ... FROM table1**